# Python lambda returning None instead of empty string

Tags: python, lambda

I have the following lambda function:

```
f = lambda x: x == None and '' or x
```

It should return an empty string if it receives None as the argument, or the argument if it's not None.

For example:

```
>>> f(4)
4
>>> f(None)
>>>
```

If I call f(None) instead of getting an empty string I get None. I printed the type of what the function returned and I got NoneType. I was expecting string.

type('') returns string, so I'd like to know why the lambda doesn't return an empty string when I pass None as an argument.

I'm fairly new to lambdas so I might have misunderstood some things about how they work.

Comment: You've committed one of the Classic Blunders...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

use the if else construct

```
f = lambda x:'' if x is None else x
```

Answer (score 8):

The problem in your case that '' is considered as boolean False. bool('') == False.
You can use

```
f =lambda x:x if x is not None else ''
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that Python treats the empty string as False.  When you pass None to your function, it evaluates to:

```
None == None and '' or None
```

which (effectively) becomes:

```
True and False or None
```

then:

```
False or None
```

and finally:

```
None
```

One solution would be:

```
lambda x: x if x is not None else ''
```

If you know x will be either a string or None, then you can leverage the fact that None is also a False value in Python:

```
lambda x: x or ''
```

Answer (score 3):

Python gives `and` a higher precedence than `or`, so the parentheses fall here:

```
lambda x: (x == None and '') or x
```

When passed `None`, this becomes `(True and '') or None`. Python’s boolean operators work by returning one argument or another (whence this little trick), so this reduces to `'' or None`, and finally `None`.

This little trick stems from back before Python 2.5, which didn't have the [conditional operator](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/). The caveat, which you just ran into, is that it doesn’t behave as expected when `True` branch has a `False` value. Unless you’re concerned with Python ≤ 2.4, just use the conditional operator.

Answer (score 2):

It's not lambdas that are the problem here. It's the pythonic if/else expressiong you are using there.

`(condition) and (expression1) or (expression2)` most of the times means the `(condition) ? (expression1) : (expression2)` you'd expect, except when `expression1` evaluates to False.

This is because the whole thing is evaluated in order. If `condition` fails, `expression1` is evaluated. If it is `True`, it is returned, due to short circuit evaluation, hence the expected behaviour. If not, `expression2` is returned. `''` evaluates to False.

Comment: Yeah the and/or pattern is not very Pythonic.. don't use it! Keep It Simple, Stupid!

Answer (score 2):

Try [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation):

```
 >>> g = lambda x: x or ''
 >>> g(3)
 3
 >>> g(None)
 ''
 >>> # beware that ...
 >>> g(0)
 ''
```

Comment: I don't think `g(0)` returns what OP wants.